# Webform never stops loading after speak using SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-to-speech

i was using speech class to play text to speech in ASP.NET website
after successfully playing the text the page load never stops. It keeps on loading for an indefinite time. And so I cannot click on next to speak the next work

```
 sp.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
 sp.Volume = 100;
 sp.SpeakAsync(rword.partofspeech);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build a prompt (or provide SSML) that first plays an audio file (i.e. uses the audio SSML tag), and then has some text to speak after that, the SpeechSynthesiser does not honor your Cancel request once it has started speaking the text (although it will happily Cancel if it is still playing the audio file).
if you put the text first (before the audio file), everything works as expected (you can Cancel the speaking of the text or the playback of the following audio file).
building a prompt with just text to speak can be Cancelled with no problems.

**work-around:**

Instead of building a prompt with both an audio file followed by the text to speak, you build two prompts, the first with just the audio file, and the second with just the text to speak.

You then call SpeakAsync on both prompts (in the correct order).

Now when you call SpeakAsyncCancelAll, it will Cancel whatever prompt is playing (whether it is the audio file prompt or the speaking prompt). The SpeakCompleted handler is invoked as expected for each prompt that was cancelled.

You can also use SpeakAsyncCancel(prompt), although you would need to call it for each prompt that you created.

NB not sure why it doesn't actually work properly when you build a prompt that contains first an audio file, then text to speak, though.